# How to get Pinta not crashing and Zoom working on 19.10

Tags: 19.10, pinta

[Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/) is a nice & simple image bitmap drawing app
It works well on 18.04 LTS but have some issues with 19.10

- Localized version cannot zoom
- Some crashes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, as [Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/) runs with [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/), get the latest version of the runtime.

```
# Check current Mono version
mono -V
#
sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
#
# Check the new Mono version
mono -V
```

Install Pinta from official Ubuntu repo

```
sudo apt install pinta
```

Disable localization
Simply make the .desktop launcher to start Pinta with `LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'` envar

```
sed -i.BACKUP 's|Exec=pinta %F|Exec=sh -c "LANG='"'"'en_GB.UTF-8'"'"' /usr/bin/pinta %F"|g' /usr/share/applications/pinta.desktop
# Or edit the file and replace
# Exec=pinta %F #by:
# Exec=sh -c "LANG='en_GB.UTF-8' /usr/bin/pinta %F"
```